# Showing Unresponsive script error on browser in UI5 javascript code

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a script where I am making 5 AJAX-based API calls for each iteration. And the JavaScript bound to take some time due to a lot of API calls and the API calls are not async. Is there any way to fix the unresponsive script error using my code?

After some research, I found that the browsers have a time limit to wait for the javascript code to complete execution. After that browsers will show unresponsive script error message.

I don't want the browser to show unresponsive script error to the end-user. Please advise if there is any way to suppress the error.

Comment: *the API calls are not async* and thats the problem

Comment: I have to live with calls in async only @JonasWilms. I also exploring different options to optimize. But wanted to check if there is a way or work around to suppress the error message.

Comment: I dont think you can suppress the message, but why can't you switch to async API calls?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @luuksen. I am working towards it.

Comment: ì`m a kind of sure its impossible to make sync api calls with the ui5 api. How did you do this?